# Invoke-Command failed: WinRM cannot complete the operation

Tags: powershell, remote-access, invoke-command, winrm

Using 2 machines, a local and a remote (with an address marked as `remoteAddress`), I'm trying to run this on the local machine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteAddress -ScriptBlock { dir c:\ }
```

but I get this error:

```
[remoteAddress] Connecting to remote server remoteAddress failed with the
following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that
the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over
the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled
and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception
for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local
subnet.
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (remoteAddress:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken
```

I followed fixes to similiar situations. What I've checked:

- Pinging to the remote address was successful.
- On both machines `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` returned

  ```
  WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
  WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
  ```
- on both machines `Set-WSManQuickConfig` returned

  ```
  WinRM is already set up to receive requests on this computer.
  WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
  ```

But still, I get this error trying to connect to the remote machine.

---

I ran `test-wsman -ComputerName _remote-machine_ -Port 5985` from my local-machine And I got this error:

```
test-wsman : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer
name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service
is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits
access to remote computers within the same local subnet. 
At line:1 char:1
+ test-wsman -ComputerName _remote_ -Port 5985
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (_remote-machine_:String) [Test-WSMan], InvalidOperationExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WsManError,Microsoft.WSMan.Management.TestWSManCommand
```

Comment: The error message points you towards [`Get-Help about_Remote_Troubleshooting`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847850.aspx). Did you follow the instructions given there?

Comment: Yes, I changed the policy settings and enabled the following:
Computer configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>
Windows Remote Management (WinRM)>WinRM Service
-Allow remote server management through WinRM
-Allow CredSSP authentication
-Turn On Compatibility HTTP Listener
-Turn On Compatibility HTTPS Listener
Windows Remote Shell
-Allow Remote Shell Access
Network>Network Connections>Windows Firewall>Domain Profile
-Windows Firewall: Allow ICMP exceptions
-Windows Firewall: Allow local port exceptions
But unfortunately, none of these steps has solved my problem.

Comment: Are the computers in a domain or a workgroup environment? Can you telnet port 5985 on the remote host?

Comment: The computers are in the same domain,
'telnet _remote-ip_ 5985' works.

Comment: Check the output of `winrm get winrm/config` on both hosts.

Comment: I marked in red the changes between the ‘winrm get winrm/config’ output in both machines [link](http://imgur.com/a/RJOyo?)

Comment: Looks like the server is configured to use CredSSP, but the client isn't.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem. I changed the CredSSP values in both of the machines to be true and false together but the error remain the same.

What do you think about the [source=”GPO”]?

Comment: AFAICT it's just indicating that the setting was applied via GPO.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the remotes to your local trusted host list? If not you can add them via

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputer"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I ran it and this is the output:
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = true
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = * 

But it still not works...

Comment: This is for computers in a workgroup environment. Do not use it for domain members.

Comment: Are the ports 5985, 5986 may be occupied by another process? You could also try `test-wsman`, maybe it delivers some usefull hints.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an active remote session, like Remote Desktop, to the computer?

I have experienced that that can be the only reason for Invoke-Command to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your NetConnectionProfile should be Private.
[image]

And here is the reason for the public profile.
[image]

In my case, it got worked after changing NetConnectionProfile as Private from Public. I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: IPv4 Filter]Ensure that the IPv4 filter in the (enabled) "Allow remote server management through WinRM" policy setting is complete, either with an asterisk * if this is appropriate, or otherwise with a list or range of IP addresses. Leaving it blank will result in this message.